# Recommended Multithreading books in .Net / C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Does anyone have any books written for .net that deal with multithreading?  I've looked at Joe Duffy's and Joseph Albahari's books, and they're good.  I was hoping however, to have something that also touches on PLINQ and TPL, which Duffy's book certainly does, but many of its examples and snippets are in C++.  I was ideally looking for something a little more C# oriented.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[C# 4.0 in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596800963) hasn't been released yet, but you can access the manuscript online.  It covers the PLINQ/TPL libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Joe Duffy's [Concurrent Programming on Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest, based on his past excellent work, waiting for [the second edition](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2009/09/29/2ndEditionOfConcurrentProgrammingOnWindows.aspx) of Joe Duffy's seminal Concurrent Programming on Windows if new features in the 4.0 .Net release are what you are after.

Since you are looking for info on an, as yet unreleased, API anything you get now, as opposed to March 2010 is likely to be not quite up to date (or worse will have inaccurate advice - a serious flaw in concurrent programming as small, seemingly trivial aspects can be very important).

To tide you over in the mean time you can read his [blog](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/default.aspx)